# Initialize the value in default constructor of an "array" class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When I try to print out the value inside this array with the default constructor of the initial value, it's all random garbage numbers.

I thought the default constructor would automatically assign the value into (0,0), but it seems like it's not. I was wondering what I should do.[image]

```
// default constructor that allocates 10 elements
Array::Array()
{
    m_size = 10;
    m_data = new Point[m_size];
}
```

Here is my private member for the class:

```
class Array {
private:
    int m_size;
    Point* m_data;
```

Also, if I try to do a colon syntax as
`Array::Array():m_size(10),m_data(new Point[10])`
it's still giving me random number.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally include a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. For example, it would be helpful to see how you are printing the output.

Comment: Please post the output as text, not as an image. You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Comment: Can you show the constructor of your `Point`?

Comment: Unlike whatever language you are used to, zero-initialisation is usually NOT the default behaviour in C++.   `m_data = new Point[m_size];` dynamically allocates an array of default-initialised elements which is not (necessarily) zero-initialisation.    From the behaviour you describe, default construction of a `Point` leaves its members uninitialised.   Either ensure `Point` has a default constructor that *explicitly* initialises members to zero (like you expect) or, in the constructor of `Array`, loop over elements to initialise all `Point`s as needed

Comment: @Peter That's super helpful! Problem solved, and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the array like this:

```
m_data = new Point[m_size](); // Add the braces on the end for zero itialization.
```

This also works in the initializer list:

```
Array::Array()
    : m_size_(10)
    , m_data(new Point[m_size]())
{}
```

Comment: `m_data(new Point[m_size]())` default-initialises the elements of `m_data`.   That is not (necessarily) zero-initialisation.

Comment: In the old days the C++ standard was simpler. You can find the correct name of this form of initialization in Section: `9.4.1 General [dcl.init.general]`. But if we want to be pedantic I believe this is `value-initialization`. See Section **`(15.4) — If the initializer is (), the object is value-initialized.`**. Which will do `default-initialized` or `zero-initialization` as appropriate. See Section `8 To value-initialize an object of type T means:` ;-)